# Problem with Hibernate Shards & JNDI

Tags: java, hibernate, jndi, sharding

I'm trying to run a sample program for hibernate shards. 
I'm all done with it but whenever I run the test program I get an Exception

`javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property`

After googling I got to know that I've to set the JNDI properties. I did like this

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
env.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, "<some-IP>:3306" );
Context initialContext = new InitialContext(env);

javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:657)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
at com.hibshards.test.JNDIProperties.setProperties(JNDIProperties.java:18)
at com.hibshards.test.SessionFactoryImpl.createSessionFactory(SessionFactoryImpl.java:32)
at com.hibshards.test.ShardTest.main(ShardTest.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:46)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:654)
... 6 more
```

But still things are not working.:-( 
Please help. What n where I'm missing?

Here is the code :

```
public class SessionFactoryImpl {

    private static final String SHARD_CFG_0 = "/com/hibshards/config/shard0.hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static final String SHARD_CFG_1 = "/com/hibshards/config/shard1.hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static final String SHARDED_TABLE = "com/hibshards/orm/weather.hbm.xml";

    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() throws NamingException {
        Configuration prototypeConfig = new Configuration().configure( SHARD_CFG_0 );
        prototypeConfig.addResource( SHARDED_TABLE );

        List<ShardConfiguration> shardConfigs = new ArrayList<ShardConfiguration>();
        shardConfigs.add( buildShardConfig( SHARD_CFG_0 ) );
        shardConfigs.add( buildShardConfig( SHARD_CFG_1 ) );

        ShardStrategyFactory shardStrategyFactory = buildShardStrategyFactory();
        ShardedConfiguration shardedConfig = new ShardedConfiguration(
                prototypeConfig,
                shardConfigs,
                shardStrategyFactory);
        return shardedConfig.buildShardedSessionFactory();
    }

    private static ShardStrategyFactory buildShardStrategyFactory() {

        ShardStrategyFactory shardStrategyFactory = new ShardStrategyFactory() {
            public ShardStrategy newShardStrategy(List<ShardId> shardIds) {
                RoundRobinShardLoadBalancer loadBalancer = new RoundRobinShardLoadBalancer( shardIds );
                ShardSelectionStrategy pss = new RoundRobinShardSelectionStrategy( loadBalancer );
                ShardResolutionStrategy prs = new AllShardsShardResolutionStrategy( shardIds );
                ShardAccessStrategy pas = new SequentialShardAccessStrategy();
                return new ShardStrategyImpl( pss, prs, pas );
            }
        };
        return shardStrategyFactory;
    }

    private static ShardConfiguration buildShardConfig( String configFile ) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure( configFile );
        return new ConfigurationToShardConfigurationAdapter( config );
    }
}

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

  <hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory name="HibernateSessionFactory0"> 
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shardDB</property>
   <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.shard_id">0</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.shard.enable_cross_shard_relationship_checks">true</property> 
  </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>


public class JNDIProperties { 
public static void setProperties() throws NamingException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    properties.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:///");
    Context initialContext = new InitialContext( properties );
  }
          }
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that the JDNI environment is properly setup  (the provider URL seems to be using a mysql port which is very strange). Please provide more details about what your code is doing. What are you trying to lookup? What app server are you using? Also please add the full stack trace.

Comment: I'm trying to create a sharding env. Kind of demo app. 
Its not using any server. My DB resides at two different machines, so, i passed  the Ip address of that machine. 
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the **full** stacktrace.

Comment: Need `JNDIProperties` and `shard0.hibernate.cfg.xml` too.

Answer (score 2):

In a simple java application, you don't need a name for the session factory..try removing the name in your cfg.xml file  and executing it